# Somar faltas consecutivas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um módulo de diário on line, preciso obter alunos com 3 faltas consecutivas, segue o select de entrada, quando o aluno tem mais de 2 horas de aula, o select exibe diferente.

```
<select name="d_status[<?=$i?>]" size="1">

<? if ($thora > 2 ) { ?>

<option value="3" <?php if ( $d_status == 3 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Presença+Presença</option>
<option value="4" <?php if ( $d_status == 4 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Presença+Falta</option>
<option value="5" <?php if ( $d_status == 5 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Falta+Presença</option>
<option value="6" <?php if ( $d_status == 6 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Falta+Falta</option>

<? } else { ?>

<option value="1" <?php if ( $d_status == 1 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Presença</option>
<option value="2" <?php if ( $d_status == 2 ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Falta</option>

<? } ?>
</select>
```

A soma total eu tenho:

```
$sql_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ****** WHERE 
                        `d_matricula` = '" . $res_['matricula'] . 
                        "' AND `d_ano_semestre` = '" . $sem . 
                        "' AND `d_filial` = '" . $filial . 
                        "' AND `d_curso` = '" . $curso . 
                        "' AND `d_dias` = '" . $dias . 
                        "' AND `d_horario` = '" . $horario . 
                        "' AND d_status = '2' AND MONTH(d_data) = '" . $mes . 
                        "' AND YEAR(d_data)= '".$ano."'"));
```

A estrutura da tabela aonde salvo os status de presença ou falsa:

```
- Estrutura da tabela `jos_users_cursos_diarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `jos_users_cursos_diarios` (
  `d_matricula` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `d_ano_semestre` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `d_filial` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `d_curso` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `d_dossie` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `d_dias` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `d_horario` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `d_data` date NOT NULL,
  `d_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `d_obs` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Olá Alexandre, o ideal para conseguirmos te ajudar é você editar sua pergunta colocando sua estrutura de tabela onde você deseja obter os alunos com 3 faltas consecutivas.

Comment: faltas consecutivas tipo sexta, segunda e terça tipo calendário escolar ou dia útil, ou somente se for sequenciado mesmo ?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente como está sua estrutura do banco de dados, mas eu faria algo assim:

```
    $where = array();

    $where[] = "`d_matricula` = '{$res_['matricula']}' ";
    $where[] = "`d_ano_semestre` = '$sem' ";
    $where[] = "`d_filial` = '$filial' ";
    $where[] = "`d_curso` = '$curso' ";
    $where[] = "`d_dias` = '$dias' ";
    $where[] = "`d_horario` = '$horario' ";
    $where[] = "`d_status` = 2 ";
    $where[] = "DATE_FORMAT(d_data, '%Y-%m') = '{$ano}-{$mes}' ";

$SQL = "SELECT tabela_alunos.*,
             ( SELECT SUM(d_faltas)
               FROM tabela_faltas
               WHERE tabela_alunos.d_id=fk_de_faltas ) total_faltas,
             ( SELECT SUM(d_presencas)
               FROM tabela_presencas
               WHERE d_id=fk_de_faltas ) total_presencas,
        WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Caso os dados estejam na mesma tabela, basta agrupar assim:

```
$SQL = "SELECT tabela_alunos.*,
                tabela_alunos.d_matricula,
                SUM(d_faltas) as total_faltas,
                SUM(d_presencas) as total_presencas,
        WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where) . " GROUP BY tabela_alunos.d_matricula";

$query = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($SQL));
```

Comment: Olá Ivan, me parece que é só a soma que exemplificou, isso já tenho, seria mostrar quando o aluno tiver 3 faltas consecutivas...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi d_status = 6 é falta certo? então segue a consulta para 3 faltas consecutivas:

```
SELECT distinct d_matricula, d_status, d_data as Dia1,
        (SELECT d_data from jos_users_cursos_diarios as t2 WHERE d_status=6 and t2.d_matricula=t.d_matricula and t2.d_data=date_add(t.d_data, INTERVAL 1 DAY) limit 1) AS Dia2, 
        (SELECT d_data from jos_users_cursos_diarios as t3 WHERE d_status=6 and t3.d_matricula=t.d_matricula and t3.d_data=date_add(t.d_data, INTERVAL 2 DAY) limit 1) AS Dia3      
    FROM jos_users_cursos_diarios t 
    WHERE d_status=6 and d_data between '2015-11-05' and '2015-11-17' group by Dia2 having Dia3 ;
```

Ali onde tem esse trecho de código `between '2015-11-05' and '2015-11-17'` é o período que irá pesquisar, caso precisar de tudo é só remover caso seja outro período é só ajustar.